# Saving non-tempogeospatial data in GeoMesa

Tags: accumulo, geomesa

Given that I use Geomesa to store tempogeospatial data in Geomesa, I also want to store non-tempogeospatial data. What Geomesa API do you recommend for this: Geomesa Native API or Geomesa DataStore API? Even better (I think) can I access native Accumulo API from Geomesa to store my data without geospatial and temporal indices?

Answer (score 0):

The native API is just a simplified wrapper around the data store API, that hides some of the complexity of working with geotools. If the native API covers your use case, then it may be easier to work with. Otherwise, use the data store API.

GeoMesa support schemas that do not have a date or geometry; however the project's primary goal is spatial indexing, and it is probably not the best solution for non-spatial data. Additionally, some features may not work without a geometry. The native API, in particular, requires both a geometry and date attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A compulsory POINT field is required. If the field is not present in data store it directly in accumulo.